# dotless doesn't compile Mixins functions in my ASP .Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, mixins, dotless

I use dotless in my ASP .Net MVC application. It compiles .less files good. but if I use Mixins functions in my .less file, error me that "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain" . If I remove Mixins function from my .less file, everything works fine.
What's my fault?

I use ASP.Net MVC 3 on Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 (IIS 7).

**Edited:**

.LESS Input

```
body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.border-all-around (@defaultBorder: 1px, @defaultColor: black)
{
  border: @defaultBorder solid @defaultColor;
}

.MyStandardBox
{
  .border-all-around;
}   
a
{
    color: #12aee8;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Output:

```
body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Result after Maxins function truncated!

Answer (score 0):

"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain"

I'm not sure if that would be of any help, but I got this error many times when using Cassini- which doesn't handle mime types very well.

Are you using IIS 7 that is bundled with windows or maybe cassini starts?
Have you tried IIs Express maybe?

If that is of no help to you, just ignore it.

Comment: I test it by IIS7 and VS 2010 ASP web server, both.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I reference to dotless.Core that its version is 1.0.0.3. I replace it by newer version (1.3.0.0) and the problem solved.